# Accessing an object accross different view functions in Flask

Tags: design, object-oriented

I am experimenting with an web app for searching and buying bus tickets. I came up with a few objects like RequestedRoute, Passenger, and Ticket:

I have some Flask view functions as well. The `home` function is called when the user visits the home page. The home page has a form where the user can enter the `departure`, `destination`, etc and there's Search button as well.

```
def home():
    return index.html
```

The `search` function is called when the user presses the `Search` button. A `RequestedRoute` object will be created, and a `RequestedRoute.get_available_routes()` method will be triggered and the available routes will be listed on the webpage and there will be a `Select` button next to each route.

```
def search():
    requested_route = RequestedRoute("fetch data from the HTML form")
    return "available_routes.html"
```

The select function will be triggered when the user selects a route and a payment_details.html page containing a form with name, surname, and card credit details will be rendered.

```
def select():
    return "payment_details.html"
```

My question is this: In the `select` function I need to know the number of travelers so that I can let the payment_details.html template know how many user forms to create where the user can enter the name, surname for each passenger. Should I instantiate a RequestedRoute object again? That feels reduntant as I did that once in the `search` function when the user searched for available routes. How can I access the `RequestedRoute` data again in the select function?

Comment: Why would `RequestedRoute` know anything about the number of travelers in the party? That information seems unneeded for calculating the available routes.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau some routes on the database have no more seats available for instance. Therefore, `RequestedRoute.get_available_routes()` has to send the number of travellers to the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for the `select` function to know that the `search` function has used the number of travelers to filter the set of available routes.

If the `RequestedRoute` class did not use the party size, this information would have to be passed to the `select` function by the front-end HTML form.
When the `select` function doesn't know if the `RequestedRoute` class has information on the (exact) party size, then that information should also be provided by the front-end HTML form.

So, my recommendation would be that the "available_routes.html" page contains a (hidden) field with the party size, so that the `select` function can pick the information from there.

Comment: Yes, Javascript seems to be the answer here.